# building msi installer and separate installation files

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

Is it possible to build msi file using installshield, so that I have one small msi that is installing files from separate folder, instead of having one biggler msi file that contains everything that is to be installed? The point is having msi installer and being able to replace files that are to be installed (if i want to update them sometime later) instead of rebuilding the whole project once i change some updated files.

Comment: What sort of files do you need to replace (and/or what sort of files do you not need to replace)? It's possible that a single MSI is not the right architecture for your needs, and that some of the files can be separated out into a dependency package.

Comment: .net framework installer for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported by MSI packages.

It doesn't matter if the files are placed in a folder next to the MSI or in a CAB archive. The actual file information is stored in the MSI database. So you cannot replace the installation files without updating the MSI.